# Authenticate App using X.509 certificate on Android

Tags: java, android, security, x509certificate, x509certificate2

My app needs to validate an X.509 certificate before sending username/password for verification.
Client X.509 certificate is already installed on Android device in "Trusted Credentials".
I am not sure now how to validate it. 
I am assuming the steps would be as follows but don't know how to use the java.security.cert or similar API to do this:

1. From the "User" tab (not System), open my X.509 certificate and get reference to it.
2. Validate things like - valid expiration, issuer, revocation list etc.

Can someone help please?

Thanks
Sandeep

Comment: in what form do you receive the X509Certificate? is it an `X509Certificate` object, a `byte[]` or a `PEM string` or something else? is it the certficiate of the server?

Comment: well, you'll probably use SpongyCastle in the end.